# Share permission odd behavior

Tags: security, permissions, network-share, ntfs

I have a odd permission issue since I switched to Server 2016. Had no issue with the same share permissions under 2012 R2.

Share is always set to Everyone FC and I always manage the permissions with NTFS ones.

When I look under the effective access tab it says that my full control group is limited by share. But share is set to Everyone Full Control!

Any clue what is going on?

[image: Effective Access]

[image: Share Access]

[image: Group Permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to verify permissions using 'net share' and 'icacls'. Make sure the share path and file path match, and that you see Everyone and FULL permissions:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> net share share
Share name        share
Path              c:\share
Permission        Everyone, FULL

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> icacls c:\share
c:\share Everyone:(F)
```

Edited: Provided better example. As far as 'effective permissions' showing the 'share' limitation, try using an actual user account instead of a group.

Comment: You are right. The moment I verified a member of the same group in effective permissions it was fine. All green! :) Many Thanks! Any clue why I can't verify a group correctly? Is it by design?

Comment: I haven't gotten a straight answer for that, groups have always shown red.

Answer (score 2):

Groups are not a member of "Everyone" - only users are.

Comment: It wasn't clear first but eventually figured out. I was wrong assuming everyone means anyone who connect to the share, including groups since they are already part of the user list. Thanks for replying, even a year late can bring useful content!